# Confused about BinarySearch in array

Tags: c#, binary-search

I am a little bit confused about BinarySearch because in a lot of cases it doesn't work. The program below dispays -5 and -1. But it should display 1 and 3 am I right?

```
using System;

namespace Binary
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] array = { 12, 45, 23, 3, 67, 43 };
            int index1 = Array.BinarySearch<int>(array, 45);
            int index2 = Array.BinarySearch<int>(array, 3); 
            Console.WriteLine(index1);
            Console.WriteLine(index2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about how binary search works. The basic assumption is "if the current item is too small then the target item is above it". That isn't true in your array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a **BinarySearch** to work, the array needs to be **sorted**. Yours is not, so it does not work correctly.

[Quote: "Searches an entire one-dimensional sorted array for a specific element"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y15ef976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly states, `BinarySearch()` only makes any sense if the array is sorted:

> *array* must be sorted before calling this method.

Answer (score 2):

Binary searches only work on a sorted array. The negative numbers are being returned because the search is not finding your values. They are documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx

Order your list before searching and it should return the correct values. If you don't want to order the list, use `IndexOf` instead of `BinarySearch`.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the horse's mouth:

> Searches an entire one-dimensional sorted System.Array for a specific
>   element, using the System.IComparable interface implemented by each
>   element of the System.Array and by the specified object.

You must sort your list first, in order for `BinarySearch` to do it's magic.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others say your array must be sorted,so just enter Array.Sort(array) after int[] array... Like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 12, 45, 23, 3, 67, 43 };
        Array.Sort(array);
        int index1 = Array.BinarySearch<int>(array, 45);
        int index2 = Array.BinarySearch<int>(array, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(index1);
        Console.WriteLine(index2);
    }
```